# Spring Boot rest service not accepting same request more than 8 request

Tags: spring, spring-boot

From remote application I am trying to fetch one product eg. **http://remotehost:8080/customers/C001/product/101** and getting the respective response on Postman.  When tried to hit same request more than 8 times then till 8th request I am getting response, but when I tried 9th same request then not getting any response just showing "Loading", so I need to restart server every time.

my code as below

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous() or #customerId.equalsIgnoreCase(authentication.getPrincipal().getFirm())")
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{customerId}/product", produces = {"application/hal+json"})
public class ProductController {
    
    @Resource(name = "productService")
    ProductService productService;
    
    @GetMapping({"/{productId}"}    )
    public HttpEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable String productId, @PathVariable String customerId){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.getProduct(productId,customerId));
    }
    
    
}
```

`

if I do code changes in code then its working properly eg. if change Pathvariable as ->
**`/{prodId}`** instead of **`/{productId}`** and **`/{custId}`** instead of **`/{customerId}`** as below

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous() or #customerId.equalsIgnoreCase(authentication.getPrincipal().getFirm())")
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{custId}/product", produces = {"application/hal+json"})
public class ProductController {
    
    @Resource(name = "productService")
    ProductService productService;
    
    @GetMapping({"/{prodId}"}   )
    public HttpEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("prodId") String productId, @PathVariable("custId") String customerId){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.getProduct(productId,customerId));
    }
    
    
}
```

then its allowing more than 8 request. why this is not working with **productId** and **customerId** PathVarialble?

Comment: from your description and without code, there are myriad possibilities cause this problem ... like the limit request of servers, synchronize/blocking in your code,  .... and so on.

Comment: Added service related code

Answer (score 0):

In my project we have already used Redis. in our Redis lock intercepter we have already configured redis lock on PathVariable eg.  **`/{productId}`** and **/`{customerId}`**. when i comment to add this interceptor in WebContext.xml then our service allowing multiple request instead on only 8 request and 8 is default in Redis property.
Now service is working.